# How to implement sntp or ntp protocol for any embedded board

Tags: networking, embedded-linux

How to implement sntp protocol for any embedded board which runs on simple linux kernel and dont have support for sntp.

Comment: do you need server or client or both?

Comment: I need client only because I am using http://tekron.com/tcg-01-g this device as server .I have to take input from it via ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build binary ntpd from busybox .

http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ntp.client